# A problem about dividing candies

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, contest-math

We already know Euler's candy division problem as follows. How many ways are there to divide $n$ of the same candies among $k$ people so that everyone has at least $1$ candy with $n\geq k$ ? We can refer to the integer equation to solve $$x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_k=n, \text{for } x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_k\geq 1.$$ The answer to this problem is $$C^{k-1}_{n-1}=\dfrac{(n-1)!}{(k-1)!((n-1)-(k-1))!}.$$ However, what if we replace $n$ of the same candies for $n$ other candies (candies are different) ? Please help me. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: You can find an answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3327235/573047 Exchange $k$ with $n$ there obviously.

Comment: Yes. I would like to express my deep thanks to @BillyJoe.